# What is the residue field of the integer ring of $\mathbb{C}_p$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Fix a prime $p$. Let $\mathbb{C}_p$ be the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ the integer ring of $\mathbb{C}_p$. I know $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ is a local ring.

What is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$? I think it should be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: show that every $x \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$ has the same image in the residue field as some $y \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$.